# Errors using subfigure

Tags: subcaption

```
\begin{figure}[h]
   \begin{subfigure} 
       \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{section7task4_1}
       \caption{low frequency noise}
   \end{subfigure}
   \begin{subfigure} 
       \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{section7task4_2}
       \caption{spectrally narrow noise}
   \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Do any one see why I should get errors on this?

Comment: Hi, welcome. While it's reasonably clear what might be the problem from the snippet you show, it's always appreciated (and sometimes entirely necessary) if you show a complete example (similar to what I have in my answer), and also state exactly which error you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to a `minipage` environment, you have to specify the width of the `subfigure` environment, i.e. `\begin{subfigure}{<width>}`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
   \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{section7task4_1}
       \caption{low frequency noise}
   \end{subfigure}\hfill
   \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{section7task4_2}
       \caption{spectrally narrow noise}
   \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```